# malloc error in a seemingly simple code?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

My simple class `A` looks as follows:

```
class A{
   char* seq;

   public:
      A(std::string seq);
      ~A();
      void printSeq();
};

A::A(std::string& seqstr ){
    this->seq = new char[strlen(seqstr.c_str())+1]();
    strcpy(seq, seqstr.c_str());
 }
A::~A(){
   delete[] this->seq;
}
A::printSeq(){
  for(int i=0; i<strlen(seq);i++){
     std::cout << seq[i];
   }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This when called as follows, results in an error.

```
const char *args[] = {"foo", "bar", "blah", "blahblah"};
std::vector<std::string> x(args, std::end(args));
std::vector<A> avec;
for(int i=0;i<x.size(); i++){
   avec.push_back( A( x[i] ) );
   avec[i].printSeq();
}
```

The error is as follows:

> foo malloc: *** error for object 0x7fea78610930: pointer being freed
>   was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug Abort trap: 6

I am not quite sure what causes this error. What is confusing to me is that 1) we do create a dynamic array here, and 2) and copy the elements of the input string. Is this a scope issue? I would appreciate any help in resolving this.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: `A` doesn't provide a copy constructor, and the compiler-generated one simply copies over `seq`. So you end up with two instances of `A` both holding the same pointer, both believing they own it, and both `delete`ing it in their destructors. Your program therefore exhibits undefined behavior, by way of double deallocation.

Comment: You need to define copy and assignment operator.

Comment: Igor you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks @IgorTandetnik and user1438832. That was quite subtle.

Comment: @mskb Not really. It's [a well-known pitfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link!

Comment: Read about [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).